# htaccess advice - how do I write this rule?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm not going to lie. I suck at writing htaccess rules. I'm ok with regexes though.

Ok, basically, user enters url: www.site.com/page.id or www.site.com/folder/page.id

That should be internally written to: www.site.com/index.php?page=id

I've got the stuff sorted in the index.php, but I just can't seem to hack it with the htaccess.

What do you suggest it should be?

EDIT: business/legal/service-level-agreement.10 and services.5 would need to work, so the rule would need to get the digit after the dot, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)?([^/]+)\.(\d+)$ index.php?$2=$3
```

Comment: Actually, it works, until I have things at the third level, e.g. business/legal/service-level-agreement.10 So what I'm basically after is something that looks for a number, which has a dot, before it. It's usually in the last bit of the string.

Comment: @ct2k7: Just replace `([^/]+/)?` with `([^/]+/)*`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Take a look here maybe this can help:

[generateit](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/)

[cooletips](http://cooletips.de/htaccess/)

[webmaster-toolkit](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mod_rewrite-rewriterule-generator.shtml)

Comment: although the rule didn't work, thanks for the links :) The rule is doing exactly what the system is doing currently, looking at the whole lot.